# How can I fix "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes..." in python?

Tags: python, csv

I need to read specified rows and columns of csv file and write into txt file.But I got an unicode decode error.

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

print(your_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is perhaps that your CSV file does not use UTF-8 encoding. Find out the original encoding used for your document.

First of all, try using the default encoding by leaving out the encoding parameter:

```
with open('output.csv', 'r') as f:
    ...
```

If that does not work, try alternative encoding schemes that are commonly used, for example:

```
with open('output.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Actually,I tried default but again I got error like this:UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode...

Comment: Can you specify the version of Python that you're using and share the complete error message?

Comment: Python version is 3.6 . Error like this when I used default encoding:     
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mavi/Desktop/Makale/SplitCSV/Splitted.py", line 5, in <module>
    your_list = list(reader)
  File "C:\Users\Mavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 632: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: And what is the error message with "utf-8" encoding?

Comment: Like this:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mavi/Desktop/Makale/SplitCSV/Splitted.py", line 5, in <module>
    your_list = list(reader)
  File "C:\Users\Mavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 17-18: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Can you try printing out the lines like this:


import csv
    with open('output.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in spamreader:
            print(row)

Comment: Okey,I  tried but again charmap error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mavi/Desktop/Makale/SplitCSV/Splitted.py", line 5, in <module>
    for row in spamreader:
  File "C:\Users\Mavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 632: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I think either the document has non-English characters or your system's locale is set to something different.

Comment: My document contains twitter data such as tweets,user ids,user names and dates.There are more than 1 million rows.Tweets are crawled as English.

Comment: Try reading using other encoding schemes like:
 encoding = "cp1252" or encoding = "ISO-8859-1"

Comment: When I tried encoding="ISO-8859-1" , I got a different error like this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mavi/Desktop/Makale/SplitCSV/Splitted.py", line 5, in <module>
    for row in spamreader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Comment: My last resort answer without seeing the CSV would be to simply open this CSV in Notepad++ and save as UTF8 encoded file

Comment: Okey,it happened now with encoding="ISO-8859-1".Thank you very much for your efforts.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :) Please consider upvoting the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you get a unicode decode error with this code, it is likely that the csv file is not  utf-8 encoded... The correct fix is to find what is the correct encoding and use it.

If you only want quick and dirty workarounds, Python offers the `errors=...` option of `open`. From the documentation of `open` function in the standard library:

> **'strict'** to raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error. The default value of None has the same effect.
>   **'ignore'** ignores errors. Note that ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss. 
>   **'replace'** causes a replacement marker (such as '?') to be inserted where there is malformed data. 
>   **'surrogateescape'** will represent any incorrect bytes as code points in the Unicode Private Use Area ranging from U+DC80 to U+DCFF. These private code points will then be turned back into the same bytes when the surrogateescape error handler is used when writing data. This is useful for processing files in an unknown encoding. 
>   **'xmlcharrefreplace'** is only supported when writing to a file. Characters not supported by the encoding are replaced with the appropriate XML character reference &#nnn;. 
>   **'backslashreplace'** replaces malformed data by Python’s backslashed escape sequences. 
>   **'namereplace'** (also only supported when writing) replaces unsupported characters with \N{...} escape sequences.

I often use `errors='replace'`, when I only want to know that there were erroneous bytes or `errors='backslashreplace'` when I want to know what they were.

Comment: I tried but I got a different error like this: _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte